# Read contents of binary file (hex), knowing the format

Tags: matlab, hex

On a laptop using Win10 x64, I have used a software that saves histogram data to a file with the '.dat' extension, and am trying to open it on Win7 x64.

In the software documentation, the file has the following format:

1. bytes 0 to 7 are a 64 bit floating point describing a number (upper bound of the diagram)
2. bytes 8 to 15 are a 64 bit floating point describing a number (bottom bound of the diagram)
3. bytes 16 to 19 are an unsigned 32 bit integer set to 0 or 1
4. bytes 20 to 23 are an unsigned 32 bit integer set to 0 or 1
5. bytes 24 to 27 are an unsigned 32 bit integer set to the width of the diagram, in pixels
6. bytes 28 to 31 are an unsigned 32 bit integer set to the height of the diagram, in pixels
7. bytes 32 to 800031 have an unsigned 32 bit integer for each point in the diagram, given the width and height. (so its 4*width*height = 800 000)

Now, if I open the file with a hex editor, I can see these values corresponding to the above numbered points:

1. `'11 EA 2D 81 99 97 71 3D'`
2. `'49 AF BC 9A F2 D7 7A 3E'`
3. `'01 00 00 00'`
4. `'00 00 00 00'`
5. `'F4 01 00 00'`
6. `'90 01 00 00'`
7. the rest of the file

From what I can see, looking at the value for 3, and knowing that should be either 1 or 0 I can see that it should actually read `'00 00 00 01'`. Reading a bit of info online, I think this is 'Little-endian'.

Writing the following in Matlab, on my Win7 laptop, `[cinfo, maxsize, ordering] = computer`, I get the answer `'L'`. And the character encoding in Matlab is 'windows-1252'.

Testing the resulting values with various tools online I got the following:

- Using http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/64bit.html for 1.
  and inputting the bytes as hexadecimal, little-endian (so, the value
  of `3D719799812DEA11` instead of `11EA2D819997713D`) I get the result of
  `1.000e-12`.
- Using the same url for 2. (so, the value of `3D719799812DEA11` instead
  of `11EA2D819997713D`), I get the result of 1.0001e-7 .
- Using the same url to get the value little-endianed, then inputting
  it into a site that converts unsigned int to binary, and another one
  that converts binary to decimals, for 3., 4., 5. and 6, I got the
  values of 1, 0, 500 and 400 respectively.

This means that the values for the above numbered points are:

1. 1e-12
2. 1e-7
3. 1
4. 0
5. 500 (width, in pixels)
6. 400 (height, in pixels)
7. 4*500*400 = 800 000, so it seems correct.

So, I know what I *should* find if I try to open the file in Matlab.
This is what I did so far:

```
name = 'histogram.dat';
fid = fopen(name,'r');
v = fread(fid);
```

This gives for `v` as a 800032x1 double. If I open the `v` vector I see the following:

- Column 1 to 7 (for 1.): [17;234;45;129;153;151;113]
- Column 8 to 15 (for 2.): [61;73;175;188;154;242;215;122]
- Column 16 to 19 (for 3.): [62;1;0;0]
- Column 20 to 23 (for 4.): [0;0;0;0]
- Column 24 to 27 (for 5.): [0;244;1;0]
- Column 28 to 31 (for 6.): [0;144;1;0]
- Column 32 to 8000032 (for 7.): the rest

Next, I deleted everything and then I tried to read the binary file in the following way:

```
name = 'histogram.dat';
fid = fopen(name,'r');
c1 = fread(fid,8,'float64');
c2 = fread(fid,8,'float64');
c3 = fread(fid,4,'uint32');
c4 = fread(fid,4,'uint32');
c5 = fread(fid,4,'uint32');
c6 = fread(fid,4,'uint32');
```

And now I get something totally different.

```
 c1 = [1.00e-12; 1.00e-07; 4.90e-324; 8.48e-312; -1.06e-314; -1.06e-314; -1.06e-314; -1.06e-314 ];
 c2 = [-1.06e-314; -1.06e-314; -1.06e-314; -1.06e-314; -1.06e-314; -1.06e-314; -1.06e-314; -1.06e-314];
 c3 to c6 = [2.1475e09; 2.1475e09; 2.1475e09; 2.1475e09];
```

---

So, it appears not to work as expected. How can I open the file, in Matlab, and have the same values as I expect?  Moreover, how can I open the bytes from 31 to the end?  I suppose I read each 4 bytes up to the end, and get the value?

Also, if I get the HEX values for each vector, and I do a `hex2num` (for the first 2, the float64s) or a `hex2dec` (for the next ones, the uint32s), I get the correct results. Should I also `hex2num` or `hex2dec` first the binary numbers?

Another possibility is to open the file in a normal hex editor, get the big vector imported in Matlab, swap the byte ordering with `swapbyes` then do the `hex2num/dec`. Then I'll get the correct values.

Comment: [fopen](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) has an option for determining endianness.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!    There was no need to play with the endianness, as it was the same left-end. on both machines, and on Matlab. Tried the code with and without the parameter, on fread or on fopen.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You don't need to edit your question with an answer. If you think the answer would be valuable to future users, you can post an answer to your own question with a short explanation. If you think the answer was just a typo or simple mistake then you could remove the question. As it happens, Tom has given the same answer just now with some context, so consider accepting his answer. I've rolled back your edit accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the help, Wolfie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `fread` is the number of elements to read, not the number of bytes. It will adjust the number of bytes according to the datatype you specify. So for example, to read in a single float64 to `c1` you actually want

```
c1 = fread(fid,1,'float64');
```

You need to adjust the other values accordingly. To read in the rest of the data to the end of the file, replace the second argument with `Inf`.

No need to convert to or from hex values; hex values are just about how the values are displayed on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can read whole data in byte vector with

```
bytevec = fread(fid,inf,'uint8');
```

Then you can manually arrange elements of `bytevec` by their indices (or use `reshape`) and call

```
value = cast(bytevec(i1:i2), type);
```

And then convert it to default matlab double type without changing data:

```
double_value = typecast(value,'double');
```